# How To Escape Characters When Reading JSON

Tags: python, json, freebase, mql

I need to write out all the variables in this JSON response:

```
  "result": {
    "\/common\/topic\/weblink": [
      {
        "url": "http:\/\/www.boardgamegeek.com\/boardgame\/13", 
        "description": "BoardGameGeek"
      }
    ], 
    "id": "\/en\/settlers_of_catan"
  }
```

So to get the id:

```
result.id
```

But how do I get the values for "\/common\/topic\/weblink"?

Comment: What library are you currently using to process the json?

Comment: I'm using Freebase-Python: http://code.google.com/p/freebase-python/

Comment: Based on an example provided in Freebase-Python, this should work -- result["\/common\/topic\/weblink"]["url"]  -- but it throws the error, -- TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ["\/common\/topic\/weblink"]["url"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like

```
result["\/common\/topic\/weblink"][0].url
```

(I think)

Comment: Just for clarity your example has a typo. It should be:   result["\/common\/topic\/weblink"][0].url

Comment: This ended up being the correct answer.  I was passing the result object to an html template, and for some reason unclear to me, I am having difficulty accessing keys from the JSON result, but there are no issues when accessing them within the Python class.

Comment: When I print the result straight to html I get" {u'/common/topic/weblink': [{u'url': u'http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/13/Settlers of Catan', u'description': u'BoardGameGeek'}], u'id': u'/en/settlers_of_catan'}

Answer (score 2):

`"\/common\/topic\/weblink"` resolves to the string `/common/topic/weblink`.  Any API accessing the decoded content should use the resulting unescaped data; the escaping is just part of JSON's encoding.

This works fine, using the standard JSON module included in Python, which I strongly recommend you use rather than third-party ones unless you have a very strong reason to be different:

```
import json

json_data = r"""
{
  "result": {
    "\/common\/topic\/weblink": [
      {
        "url": "http:\/\/www.boardgamegeek.com\/boardgame\/13",
        "description": "BoardGameGeek"
      }
    ],
    "id": "\/en\/settlers_of_catan"
  }
}"""

data = json.loads(json_data)
print data["result"]["/common/topic/weblink"]
```

Note that you left out the enclosing braces on the object, which I added in.

Comment: Thanks Glenn.  I'm on Python 2.5.5 as a limitation of Google App Engine.  I believe json was introduced with 2.6.  Let me try it out.

Comment: It may be called "simplejson" if it's installed in older versions of Python.  (Note that any hosting service which is still on 2.5 in 2010 is clearly not being reasonably maintained, and shouldn't be considered for anything nontrivial.)

Comment: I think I'm close.  I imported simplejson.  And tried the loads function.  >>> json_result = simplejson.loads(result)  However I am getting an error (TypeError: expected string or buffer) because the result object is not a string.

Comment: Actually the reason Google App Engine uses 2.5.5 is a good one.  And they have the "inventor" of Python on the Google App Engine team.

Comment: @Will: There are no excuses for crippling a platform by using such an obsolete version of Python, and hiring Guido doesn't change that in the slightest--it makes it that much worse (but given the fiasco of Python 3, he's not exactly an authority on software upgrade paths).  Anyhow, if your JSON text isn't a string, then I don't know what you're doing--the code I showed above works normally.

Comment: @Will Merydith: If your JSON text is neither `str` nor `unicode`, then what is it?

Comment: @John good question.  I looked through the Freebase-Python library and it looks like it is also using simplejson.loads, so it should be returning a string.  I'm totally confused now.  I'm attempting to switch from 10 years of Java to Python this week and it's been interesting ;)

Comment: @John when I attempt to log the JSON result (in order to verify the object type), I get the error that it's a type "attrdict" (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/361668-attrdict-a-dict-whose-items-can-also-be-accessed-a/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
result.__getattribute__("\/common\/topic\/weblink")[0].url
```

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError: Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'result.__getattribute__'